# How to manage and refer to specific dependency libraries versions?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have my root `build.gradle` like this:

```
...
ext{
  buildToolsVersion = '23.2.1'
}
...
```

Why cannot I manage my Android support libraries version like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion}'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion}'
}
```

`${}` works in Groovy, why does not it work in Gradle?

Comment: and if you care about managing the updating of your various dependencies, you can see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237130/how-to-detect-when-dependency-library-version-updates-exist-in-build-gradle-in-a @Ben Manes has a fantastic solution. Plus, if you read in the comments of my question, he suggests a nifty way of structuring your dependencies as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

In `root/build.gradle`:

```
ext {
    //Version
    supportLibrary = '23.2.1'

    //Support Libraries dependencies
    supportDependencies = [
            design           :         "com.android.support:design:${supportLibrary}",
            recyclerView     :         "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibrary}",
            cardView         :         "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibrary}",
            appCompat        :         "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibrary}",
            supportAnnotation:         "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibrary}",
    ]
}
```

In your `module/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    //......
    compile supportDependencies.appCompat
    compile supportDependencies.design
}
```

Comment: It's my fault,your solution is great.

Comment: I like the idea of bundling the support libraries in an array. Is there a way that you can write a loop in Gradle to compile all those without individual `compile` statements?

Comment: Great solution !! but how can we check if newer version of lib is available ?

Answer (score 0):

my fault.
 `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion}'`
equals
`"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:\${rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion}"`.
so it should be `"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion}"` with **double quotes**.

Comment: You can edit your original question and don't have to post an answer with corrections to your own question.